# is there a way to operate on non 7-day date range in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a use case to operate on a 10-day window. In essence moment().startOf('week') returns the start day of the 7-day week but I need to get the start day of a range comprised of 10 days.

I am assuming something like below:

```js
moment.prototype.startOfWindow = function () {
 this.hours(0);
 var weekday = (this.day() + 10 - this.localeData()._week.dow) % 10;
 this.add(0 - weekday, 'd');

 return this;
};

moment.prototype.endOfWindow = function () {
 return this.startOfWindow().add(10, 'days').subtract(1, 'ms');
};
```

is it right?

Comment: What would you call the eighth day?  Funday?  There are not 10 days in a week so there is no concept of a week that consists of new days, this is highly illogical...

Comment: You can get the number of days since the *first* 10-day-window start and then use a simple `days % 10 == 0` on it.

Comment: why the downvote? I am not looking to add any days to the week concept. All I am looking for is the range! I want windows of 10 days and not 7 days!

Comment: @user2864740 can you post a sample please?

Comment: @samdeV http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ - just get the day difference between now and the start of the first window. You'll have to define *when* the very first window started (just as the very first week started at some time!)